# UnderscoreJS _.filter through multiple BackboneJS collections

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

How can I filter through multiple Backbone.js collections? Something like this:

```
var a = _.filter([b.models, c.models], function(model){
    return model.get('d');
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this work by combining the two models with [_.union](http://underscorejs.org/#union)

```
var combinedCollection = _.union(b.models, c.models);
var a = _.filter(combinedCollection, function(model){
    return model.get('d');
});
```

Comment: That was my first thought too.